# How i can have different names for my App based on the store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app on apple store, the name of the app in English. how i can have different name for my app, if someone access my app from Arabic country for example.

Comment: Hi, would you please share the solutions you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to localize the name of an application in the AppStore without

There are two possibilities:

1. When creating an app, set the default language to one which you want
2. Add a localization to an existing application via *App Information* tab. More details how to do it you can find on the [help pages of the iTunes Connect](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev97865727c)

[image]

**Important**

It is impossible to have two application targets with the same functionality but different languages in the AppStore. In that case Apple recommends to Localize the app and have a dedicated support page with references to all necessary tools [link](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

**App content localization (Optional)**

To localize a text content of an app, create an empty Localizable.strings file in a project

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Username"="nom d'utilisateur";
/* {User First Name}'s Profile */
"%@'s Profile"="profil de %1$@";
```

and use [`NSLocalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring) macro

```
textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Username", nil);
```

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1)

Comment: thanks Sir...let me clarify more my question. i have an app that is completely in English (names, screens, help...etc), i create new app that exactly the same English app but in Arabic, when i tried to upload the Arabic version it gets rejected immediately. so i am asking how i can upload my Arabic version.so that if the user on US store will see the english version, while if he on Saudi arabia for example will see the arabic version.

Comment: @HosamMohammedAl-Bayomi I have updated the answer. Is that response to your question

Comment: many thanks Sir... i appropriate your feedback. i saw the video in that page, but still not clear, if you know any source that explains the steps more, it would be really great help.

Comment: @HosamMohammedAl-Bayomi I have added an image which shows where you add application description additional language.